# Combing and calling Functions from different files problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm pretty new to python but I have manged to create some functioning code using selenium. I'm trying to expand on the code and at the same time make it modular.

So the program goes off to 30 websites and scrapes some data and returns it. What i'm trying to do now is create a function in a separate .py file with the code for each website scrape.
Then call the files and functions on a main.py like this :

### main.py

```
import Functions

functions.test_func()
```

### functions.py

```
def test_func():
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    import time
    driver.get('https://reddit.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

*This works fine and I'm happy with it, but of course if I could have an external function it would be easier to alter that if I needed instead of in each of the 30 files*

### I created a file called web_driver_func.py

```
def webdriver():
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

to replace

```
def test_func():
        >>>from selenium import webdriver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')<<<
        import time
        driver.get('https://reddit.com')
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.close()
```

#----# with

```
def test_func():
        import web_driver_func
        web_driver_func.webdriver()
        import time
        driver.get('https://reddit.com')
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.close()
```

But "driver" then is not defined, and I understand the logic of that. But I've been trying to search for a solution or method I have not come across yet to solve it.
I thought if I wrote it like this and exclude it form the test_func() it would work, but its the same problem :

### In main.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import Functions

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

Functions.test_func()
```

I apologize if there is a simple glaring mistake in my logic or code. Like I said I'm new to Python and its been 30 years since I last wrote any code and that was in PASCAL/TSL :(
I'd be grateful for any help and constructive criticism.

Comment: There is a capitalisation error in your examples, you import `Functions`, but reference `functions`. Python is case sensitive, you should typically reserve capitalised names for classes.

Comment: Just return `driver` from the function.

Comment: Also, this seems like an XY problem - you're trying to solve issues with a specific solution to a problem, but you're not really providing a description of the problem you're trying to solve. It seems to me that you're going about this in an overly complicated way, but you're not providing insight why the complication is there. Do you simply want to define and construct the driver once and then reuse it to download all 30 sites/pages?

Comment: `Functions` was a typo sorry :( So I'm scraping 30 different websites and attempting to have the code for each website scrape in a separate file and then call all the files one after the other as a program.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out after some YT videos lol.
Now the only thing that can alter is the web driver path in the main file

### main.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
    import functions
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    functions.test_func(driver)
```

### functions.py

```
def test_func(driver):
    import time
    driver.get('https://reddit.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```